# Is it wrong to assume that $|{-\vec r}⟩ = - |{\vec r}⟩$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, eigenvalue, parity

I found a problem that says the following:

> The 'even' operator is defined as: $$\Pi|{\vec r}\rangle = |{-\vec r}\rangle$$ Show that $\Pi$ is Hermitian and find $\Pi^2$ and its eigenvalues.

All of my work is based on the assumption that I can write the following:$$\Pi|\vec{r}\rangle = -|\vec{r}\rangle$$ but I'm not sure that it's right. If it isn't, and it's incorrect to write that $|{-\vec r}\rangle=-|\vec{r}\rangle$, then I have no idea how to solve the problem, since I have no representation of the $\Pi$ operator.

Comment: If your untrue assumption held, you'd have $|r\rangle+ |-r\rangle =0$ !!

Comment: Hint: what can you say about the states $|r\rangle \pm |-r\rangle$ ?

Comment: I'm not sure how to prove that it's wrong

Comment: Some important formatting tips: (i) use `\rangle` instead of `>`; (ii) enclose the inside of kets in braces (i.e. `|{ contents }\rangle`) whenever `contents` has a minus sign, as otherwise LaTeX will think you're subtracting $\vec r$ from `|` and space things accordingly (which will look wrong); and (iii) $\Pi$ is `\Pi`, not `II`.

Comment: Dot it with $\langle  \psi |$. Surely you don't expect all wavefunctions to be odd functions of their argument!

Comment: Ohh, ok, I got it now! Thanks! :D

Answer (score 4):

> All of my work is based on the assumption that I can write the following:$$\Pi|\vec{r}\rangle = -|\vec{r}\rangle$$

This is wrong.

- $|{-\vec r}\rangle$ is an eigenvector of the position operator $\hat{\vec x}$ with eigenvalue $-\vec r$.
- $-|{\vec r}\rangle$ is an eigenvector of the position operator $\hat{\vec x}$ with eigenvalue $+\vec r$, since
  $$
  \hat{\vec x}\left(-|{\vec r}\rangle\right)
  = -\hat{\vec x} |{\vec r}\rangle
  = -\vec r|{\vec r}\rangle
  = {\vec r}\left(-|{\vec r}\rangle\right)
  .
  $$

The eigenvalue is uniquely determined by the eigenvector, so the only way those two things can be true is if both eigenvalues are equal, i.e., if $-\vec r=\vec r$ (which itself implies $\vec r=\vec0$).

---

With this in hand:

> then I have no idea how to solve the problem, since I have no representation of the $\Pi$ operator.

Yes you do $-$ you just specified
$$\Pi|{\vec r}\rangle = |{-\vec r}\rangle, \tag 1$$
which uniquely pins down the action of that operator. If you want to turn that into a specific representation in the sense of something to put on the right-hand side of an equation that starts with $\Pi= ...$, then you can put a resolution of identity on the right of $\Pi$:
\begin{align}
\Pi
& = \Pi \, \mathbb I
= \Pi \int \mathrm d\vec r \, |\vec r\rangle\langle \vec r |
=  \int \mathrm d\vec r \, \Pi|\vec r\rangle\langle \vec r |.
\end{align}
It's your job to keep working the problem from there: your specification $(1)$ gives you a specific path ahead, and then if you want to calculate $\Pi^\dagger$ you can just take the conjugate inside the integral, which you can then manipulate (using a suitable change of variables) into a form that you can match against $\Pi$ itself.

---

Finally, to tackle $\Pi^2$, first calculate its action on $|{\vec r}\rangle$, and then repeat the jig taken above, which should produce an extremely simple expression. You should be able to read off the eigenvalues of $\Pi^2$ directly from the result of that calculation.

Comment: Shouldn't it be noted that this is somewhat an issue of notation. The first chapter of Shankar's QM book says $|-V\rangle=-|V\rangle$, but that is because they are using $|-V\rangle$ to denote the additive inverse of $|V\rangle$ rather than the state vector whose eigenvalue is $-V$ for some operator.

Comment: If Shankar uses a notation such that $|{-V}\rangle = -{|V\rangle)$ then Shankar is using highly-nonstandard notation which it is highly unadvisable to use. I see no indication that OP is using that textbook here.

Comment: I am sorry, I wasn't saying that is the text book the OP is using, nor am I claiming what is the "standard notation". What I mean is that the OP hasn't really specified what they mean by $|-\vec r\rangle$, even if it is obvious under "standard notation".

Comment: @AaronStevens The problem statement given by OP rigidly defines what that notation implies in the context that OP is working in, regardless of whether OP herself fully understands the difference between the two options or what she means by the notation.

Comment: There *is* a clear standard notation. There, $|{-\vec r}⟩$ and $-{|\vec r⟩}$ are *not* equal.

Comment: The OP seems confused about why $|-\vec r\rangle\neq-|\vec r\rangle$, and it could be because of how they have seen notation in the past. Whatever you put inside the ket is just a label after all. So I am just saying they might not realize the difference between using it to denote an additive inverse vs. the negative of some other eigenvalue

Comment: @AaronStevens Indeed. But I don't see how it is helpful to bring up non-standard notations when there is no evidence that OP is using those resources.

Answer (score 3):

A nice way to see what's happening is to construct an approximate "toy" state
$\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left|#1\right>}
\ket r
$. For instance you might construct a wavefunction that's "at" a location ten units to the right of your origin by

$$
\ket{10}=\left\{
\begin{array}{cl}
1 & \text{where } 9<x<11
\\
0 & \text{elsewhere}
\end{array}
\right.
$$

You can adjust the height if you want to normalize so that $\left<r|r\right> =1$, and adjust the width if you want a more precise version of "at."  Now, how would you construct $\ket{-10}$, ten units to the left of the origin? What about $-\ket{10}$? They are different.